# pass pointer to object by refrence in c++

Tags: c++

so im trying to pass an a pointer to an object by refrence so i can access to objects contents without having to copy them.

this is what ive tried so far.

here is the function ive created

```
int encode_frame(vpx_codec_ctx_t *codec, vpx_image_t *img,
                        int frame_index, int flags, VpxVideoWriter *writer, const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *&pkt
                              ) {...}
```

and here is how i call it

```
const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *pkt = NULL;
encode_frame(&codec, &raw, frame_count++, 0, writer, pkt);
```

Comment: If you already have a pointer, then you can access the objects members without copying. Passing a pointer by reference allows you to reset the pointer to point to something else.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Ohhhhh lol thanks clcto! Lol that explains why I was getting a segmentation fault when I try to access it lol my questions is just how to do it correctly since it wasn't working for me

Comment: You can pass an object by value, or by reference.  In C++, there are two ways to pass by reference - pass a pointer (parameter declared with `*`) or pass a reference (parameter declared with `&`).  If you want to pass `nullptr` like you do in your question, you should use a pointer.

Comment: So I got rid of the & in my function definition but I'm still getting segmentation faults when I try to access the pkt object outside of the encode_frame function